# Text font is default on Android Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

My site's text is 'Cooper Black' as dictated by in my CSS. When viewed in Android Chrome browser i see that the text is default and not Cooper Black.

I'm assuming my font is not preloaded, anything i can do?

```
.sitetext-white {
    font-family: 'Cooper Black';
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: How do i do that on the Chrome App

Comment: How are you loading the font? Show the `@import` or `@font-face`.

Comment: Unless you are making sure `Cooper Black` is available on that website: why would it be? Assume no font you attempt to use by name is available on every system unless you ensure it is, by using `@font-face` imports.

Comment: i think you are ahead of me here - i dont assume it is on every system, in fact i understand its not which is why i post the question. How do i mitigate this? You touched on a method of making the font 'available on the website' - can you expand on this?

Comment: @mr Lister, i have only got what code is in the question. I dont load the font in anyway i do not think. can you expand on 'loading the font with import or font-face?

Comment: Does this really relate to [Chrome Apps platform](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) / mobile toolchain, or did you just mean the Chrome browser itself? If the latter, please remove the tag.

Comment: the chrome browser n my laptop works fine, the font is missing from the chrome browser on my android phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cooper Black is not what we call a [Web Safe Font](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp), because it is not found on a high percentage of OS's. Even then, font's like Arial are only found on Windows machines so they need to have a fallback.

> *The font-family property should hold several font names as a "fallback" system, to ensure maximum compatibility between browsers/operating systems. If the browser does not support the first font, it tries the next font.*
>
> *Start with the font you want, and end with a generic family, to let the browser pick a similar font in the generic family, if no other fonts are available:*

If you want to use a non-standard font, we have what we call [Font Face](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp).

> *With the @font-face rule, web designers do no longer have to use one of the "web-safe" fonts.*
>
> *In the new @font-face rule you must first define a name for the font (e.g. myFirstFont), and then point to the font file(s).*

If you want to find a nice font to use with @font-face, I would suggest you head over to [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) and use the [Webfont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).

How to best set up your @font-face syntax can be found on [this article](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) by Paul Irish from Google:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Graublau Web';
    src: url('GraublauWeb.eot?') format('eot'), url('GraublauWeb.woff') format('woff'), url('GraublauWeb.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

> *This is the Fontspring @font-face syntax. I’ll circle back to why this is the best possible solution but let’s first review the other techniques’ weaknesses. Of course, the problem at the center of this is that IE needs an .eot font, and the other browsers must take a .ttf or .otf.*

If your application is on the web, you can also use [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) which has a very nice library, and means that all you need to do is link to it in your website.

Comment: nice one, so font-faces are the way to go - i'll check it out!

Comment: I have a question - when you state your ttf location, is that on your server or pointed at a url as i would expect http:// etc etc if it was hosted somewhere other than your local?

Comment: @Fearghal The example in the answer is looking for the font files in the same location as the current file. I think you could use either method though, as long as it can find the file.